# Avoid flickering when hiding and showing widget

Tags: qt, widget, qlayout

I am using a Qt Designer GUI that has some widgets that should appear alternatively. I tried to solve this by simply hiding the unwanted widgets and showing the wanted widgets using setVisible().

This works well and most times the unwanted widgets are optically replaced by the new widgets smoothly. However sometimes I can see a flickering in the layout that sems to happen because an update or something similar takes place while both of the widgets are visible at the same time.

How can this flickering be suppressed?

I tried setUpdatesEnabled() but that wasn't effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (easy) solution is to use [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html).